# Hide "You have old mail" message when logging into shell?

Tags: shell, email, postfix, dovecot, motd

I have a mail system set up on my server (Postfix + Dovecot) that I use for personal and sys-admin email. Every time I login via shell (for all of my accounts), the message "You have old mail." is displayed below the MOTD modules I've configured.

I can't delete or move (most of) my read mail elsewhere, but I'd like to hide this message; it's pointless and clutters my MOTD. I'd prefer to keep the "You have new mail." message if possible, but I'm willing to lose it if that's what it takes.

I don't think this message is from a MOTD module, and it shows up on both SSH and local.

How can I hide or remove the "You have old mail." message when logging into shell?

Comment: Is it really “You have old mail.”, or is it “You have mail”?

Comment: @StephenKitt It is really "You have old mail."

Comment: Thanks, that discriminates between bash and `pam_mail` ;-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably generated by the PAM `pam_mail.so` module.

Edit `/etc/pam.d/login` en comment out the line that looks like:

```
session    optional   pam_mail.so standard
```

Alternatively, keep the line but remove `standard` if it's there, and add `nopen` to the end.

It may be necessary to do the same in the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` file.

See `man pam_mail` for more information.

Comment: I would suggest `quiet` rather than `nopen`. That way a message will appear for new mail, but not for old.

Comment: Just a small correction; the file to edit for SSH is /etc/pam.d/sshd *not* /etc/pam.d/pam_sshd

Answer (score 1):

The message is produced by `pam_mail.so` module. Find it in the various files in `/etc/pam.d` (there may be more than one, to cover the different ways of logging in) and find a line that has `pam_mail.so standard`.  Add the verb `quiet`.

More details in the [man page](http://man.he.net/man8/pam_mail).